# Jira create link between custom issues

Tags: jira, jira-ondemand

I'm creating custom JIRA configurations OnDemand.

I want to configure two issues, called TestPlan and TestPlanRun. I want to have a link that shows that TestPlanRun is related to TestRun, it is obvious that I want to have multiple TestPlanRuns for TestRun.

I did not succeed to do it with Jira admin interface.
Can you help me? or advise some good TestPlan/TestPlanRun/TestCase/TestCaseRun workflow 
in JIRA OnDemand marketplace?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There's a comment about this at https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/AOD/Restricted+Functions+in+Atlassian+OnDemand?focusedCommentId=589366653#comment-589366653

Comment: Thank you for an answer. I meant little bit different case.
We have a link on entity "Epic link" it means that Epic is parent of a story. I want to have the same approach for link between TestPlan and TestPlanRun and I want to have many-to-many relationship between TestPlan and TestCase. So can I implement something like this on Jira OnDemand?